# PHP PDO error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having a small issues, when I submit data on my forum I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Explain, Country, IP, Hostname)
```

My code is this:

```
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `Applications` (`Username`, `Email`, `Age`, `Reason`, `Explain`, `Country`, `IP`, `Hostname`) VALUES ($username, $email, $age, $reason, $explain, $country, $ip, $hostname)");
        $STH->execute();
```

I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: That's weird. From the message shown it looks like the problem is in Explain - it's a reserved word, so it has to be wrapped into the `backtick` symbol. Yet it IS wrapped in the query shown.

Comment: And yes, you have to quote all these values (not `$username`, but `$DBH->quote($username)`)

Comment: Please do not recommend using `$DBH->quote()` directly.

Comment: @tadman Sure, using placeholders is way better.

Comment: This is apparently not a real question as it's code contradicts with error message

Answer (score 2):

You're not using PDO correctly, creating massive SQL injection problems. Values put into SQL need to be escaped properly.

The [placeholder method](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) dictates doing it this way:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO `Applications` (`Username`, `Email`, `Age`, `Reason`, `Explain`, `Country`, `IP`, `Hostname`) VALUES (:username, :email, :age, :reason, :explain, :country, :ip, :hostname)");
$STH->bindParam(':username', $username);
$STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
... (remaining columns) ..
$STH->bindParam(':hostname', $hostname);
$STH->execute();
```

This is the best way to ensure your SQL is [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: You're definitely right on this (+1), yet it doesn't looks like the reason for the error shown. Still, the problem may go away if the OP rewrites the query into this. )

Comment: BTW, one can send placeholder param values into `execute` as well.